# What Is meta_id In wp_postmeta?

Tags: posts, custom-field, meta-query, post-meta

I am trying to add some data in WordPress Custom Field and via adding more direct records/data in `wp_postmeta` table via SQL query. There are four column as mentioned below...

- 'meta_id' - A unique id for each entry.
- 'post_id' - The ID of the post for this metadata.
- 'meta_key' - The name of the 'key'.
- 'meta_value' - The value associated with the key.

Now I am using the below SQL query to add some more records/data.

```
$INSERTING_DATA = "INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) values ('XXXXXXXXX', 'WordPress_Post_ID_No', 'WordPress_Post_Custom_Field_Name', 'WordPress_Post_Custom_Field_Value')";
```

So here I am able to add all my data but I want to know that what to add in `meta_id` column ? Is that auto increment value so I have to leave that value and should I use below SQL query...???

```
$INSERTING_DATA = "INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` (`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) values ('WordPress_Post_ID_No', 'WordPress_Post_Custom_Field_Name', 'WordPress_Post_Custom_Field_Value')";
```

So Now tell me which one is correct and Ok to use. First or second...??? Also describe me that what is `meta_id` in this table?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you aren't using the `add_post_meta` function?

Comment: @TomJNowell I am doing something different. Not in WordPress but from outside of WordPress...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`meta_id` in `postmeta` table is just an **AUTO_INCREMENT** id for the table, you can easily inspect that:
[image: meta_id - AUTO INCREMENT]

So, your guess is correct, you can leave it.

#### EDIT

Avoid raw SQL statements and introduce `$wpdb` for SQL purposes. And for postmeta insertion you can see the following tutorial I found a best one:

- [Reusable Custom Meta Boxes - Code.TutsPlus.com](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-1-intro-and-basic-fields--wp-23259)

Comment: Thanks for confirming the answer... This is it what I want to confirm...I am hitting WP database from outside the WordPress so this is why I am asking this...

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using direct SQL. Consider creating a PHP script that loads WordPress core functions and uses them (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101503/include-wordpress-core-into-own-scripts#answer-9126230 for getting an idea how to do that).

- [add_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_post_meta/)
- [update_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/)

But if you do want to create custom SQL (if you are asking the question you are asking I highly do not recommend it), you should probably get more information on `postmeta` table before doing so. Let me cover the topic for you.

First of all, let's get some overview of the table:

```
mysql> describe wp40.wp_postmeta;
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| meta_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_id    | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| meta_key   | varchar(255)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| meta_value | longtext            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0,08 sec)
```

From that you can see that meta_id is `auto_increment` and thus MySQL will figure out itself what value it should add. Passing simple `0` instead of real `meta_id` is enough.

`post_id` refers back to the post to which the meta is associated. Default is `0` but you should pass a real `post_id` so you can see the meta in the custom fields editor on the post editing screen.

`meta_key` is the name of a meta. Pay attention, using a name starting with underscore eg.: `_hidden_meta` will hide the meta from custom field editor on edit screen.

`meta_value` is a longtext and can hold any text you need. But pass it strings only! (in case of an array of other objects, you can serialize the text).

But once again, consider using [add_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_post_meta/) or [update_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/) functions.

Comment: well explained the causes. nice one.

Comment: Thanks for explaining and clear out my confusion. I am hitting WP database from outside the WordPress so this is why I am asking this...